# emVideoView onKeyDown Or center (OK)

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, android-videoview, playlist

Coding with Android Studio.

I am trying to make the emVideoView work with  onKeyDown (or other keys) for keyboard or remote control on a user click to load java activity (Play list).

Here is what I tried. Instead of loading a list it is returning or exiting completely rather than loading an Activity example (VideoSelectionActivity) is my page that have all the play list.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (emVideoView != null && (emVideoView.isPlaying() || emVideoView.getFocusedChild() != null ) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN)) {
        return emVideoView.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);


    }
}



@Override
public void KeyEvent(VideoSelectionActivity arg0) {

    if (emVideoView.isPlaying()==true) {emVideoView.showDefaultControls();}
}
```

I have changed this many times and the onClick events works but incorrectly also not loading activity.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do (as in what do you want to display and when)?

Comment: I am trying to load a  playlist (video) when I click Enter Key (Hardware Keyboard) while the video still playing, so the listview that is on my layout (selection_activity_list) should popup on the side on KeyEvent.

Comment: I have tested the above code, the Enter key worked but its taking me back to main selection page and video stopped , just like return key. I am using EMVideoView from git (https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia). Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Here is the layout that I want to show on top of the video while is playing ( foreground view) called OnOkClicked <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ListView android:id="@id/selection_activity_list" android:layout_width="196dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

</RelativeLayout>.